Convert null values from json file into a empty string
i need a help from all of you.
I have to copy a json file from an S3 bucket to another S3 bucket, but this new json file must contain all the fields that have "null" value as an "" value (blank string).
You can see my sample.json file here. and the final json file on target must have something like this sample_result.json.
I try with the next code, but the result is not as i want, null values are still there:
s3_source_path = "s3://my_bucket_name/test_json_samples/sample.json"

DEST_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket_name'

columns_to_remove = ['ReportId']

df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true") \
                       .option("encoding", "UTF-8") \
                       .json(s3_source_path)

df = df.select(F.explode("Data").alias("data"), "PageNumber", "PageSize", "Message", "Errors")

f = df.select(
                *[col("data." + col_name) for col_name in df.schema["data"].dataType.fieldNames() if col_name not in columns_to_remove],
                "PageNumber", "PageSize", "Message", "Errors"
                )

df.show(3, truncate=False)

string_columns = [col_name for col_name, col_type in df.dtypes if col_type == 'string']
df = df.fillna('', subset=string_columns)  

group_by_columns = ["PageNumber", "PageSize", "Message", "Errors"]
data_columns = [col(c) for c in df.columns if c not in group_by_columns]

df = df.groupBy(group_by_columns).agg(collect_list(struct(*data_columns)).alias("Data"))

df.show(3, truncate=False)

s3_dest_path = "s3://my_bucket_name/source/raw/"
df.write.mode('append').option("dropFieldIfAllNull", "false").json(s3_dest_path)

Can somebody help me with this pyspark code?
